# Problem with add-to-list in babel src block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I execute a babel src block with `add-to-list` function like this:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes (quote ("plantuml" . fundamental)))
#+end_src
```

I will get this error message:

```
executing Emacs-Lisp code block...
orgtbl-format-line: Wrong type argument: listp, fundamental
```

The syntax is correct, as I can evaluate it on `.emacs` buffer without a problem.

The org-mode version is 8.2.10 if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When evaluating the code, Org-mode takes the return value of `add-to-list`, which is the list with the new element added, and tries to display it.  Lists are displayed as tables, but apparently it doesn't like symbols in the list.  (I'm inclined to think that this is a bug in Org-mode.)

You can work around it by asking Org-mode not to display the return value of the code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: For org-mode 8.3beta, `add-hook` may throw this error, and the same header argument can fix it. https://github.com/yitang/.emacs.d/commit/7ecfad7af6315f880d0c6b12c6f63101d44aaf7d